# Prove or disprove in propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following question - and would like to make clear some definition via it's answer -

Prove of Disprove -

If  $\\X\models\alpha$ and $\\Y\models\alpha$, then $X\cap Y\models\alpha$

1. Just to verify that intersection mean that it includes all the shared statements and union means all the statements together.
2. Get some help with this question.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is clear. But I don't understand your question. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Is intersection between two sets of statements means that the new set includes all the similar statments?

Comment: By definition $X\cap Y$ is the set whose elements are **exactly** those which are both in $X$ and $Y$. This is true for all sets, including sets of statements. Does this help? What else is troubling you?

Comment: Yeah thanks , if you just help me solve the question or give some hints.

Comment: **Hint:** It's false. Consider $\alpha=p\lor q$ where $p$ and $q$ are propositional statements. Can you find suitable $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Can u give me X - i guess finding Y will be easier then.

Comment: I will not do it. Try proving it for $p\lor q$ and see what obstacles you find.

Comment: What about - X = {$p -> q$ , $\neg q$} , Y = {$q -> p$ , $\neg q$}

Comment: You tell me, does $X\models p\lor q$ hold?

Comment: It should be - X = {$\neg p -> q ,\neg q$} ,  Y = {$\neg q -> p ,\neg q$}

Comment: MathJax Tip: `\to` gives $\to$

Comment: Git Gud, I don't see the challenge. Let $X={p}$. Clearly,it follow by Addition (in natural deduction) and by truth table (as a semantic method) that $p\vee q$. Let $Y={q}$. Again, by the same argument,it follows $p\vee q$.

Comment: Ok, but  $X \cap Y$  is the empty set which follows that the statement is true although it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

One can prove that for the union:

Let $X\models \alpha$ and $Y\models\alpha$. By the completeness theorem, we have $X\vdash\alpha$ and $Y\vdash\alpha$. That means there are derivations $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_n$ such that $x_n=\alpha=y_n$ and, for every $x_i$ and $y_i$ with $i\neq n$, $x_i$ and $y_i$ are either axioms or premisses or formulas derived from the axioms or premises in $X$ or $Y$. Since these are two different sets, there exists (by the union axiom of ZF) the union set $X\cup Y$ of axioms or premisses from both the derivations; and by the metalogical property of Monotony one knows that $X\cup Y\vdash \alpha$. Finally, aply the soundness theorem to reach $X\cup Y\models \alpha$. QED

One can not prove that for the intersection, since it is not true in general. As a counter example, Git Gub has offered in the comments section $\alpha=p\vee q$, which may not follow from the intersection of certain sets that imply it.